# How to remove generated suffix generated by Open API and Json View?

Tags: java, swagger-ui, jackson-databind, springdoc-openapi-ui

Good day to you all!

I have a DTO class that has the information of an entity. I am using `spring-docs-openapi-ui` 1.4.8 to document the project. I am using JsonViews in order to show specific attributes of my class given the type of operation, if the operation is a `GET`, I will use a Json ClassDetail view. If the operation is `PUT`, I will use a ClassUpdate view. The attributes marked in the BaseClass with either ClassDetailDTO view or ClassUpdateDTO view will be displayed in the response regarding the Operation. However, when I build and check the generated documentation, For these 2 operations, some attributes are marked with the type of view of the Operation. Is there a way to disable this?

Here's what it looks like.

EntityDTO_ClassUpdated

| Field | Data Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | string |
| identifier | IdentifierDTO_ClassUpdated[] |

EntityDTO_Write

| Field | Is Required | Data Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| identifier | No | IdentifierDTO_Write[] |

Just to clarify, is there a way to get rid of the suffix? `_Write`, `_ClassUpdated`, `_ClassDetail`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's to late for you, but the answer could help people in the future, so I share it : you can add `ignoreJsonView = true` in the annotation `@Operation`.
For example :

```
@Operation(summary = "Retrieve a todo by id", ignoreJsonView = true)
```

How I found it ? I downloaded the source code from the [public repository](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) and searched for `@JsonView`. In the code you can find a way to ignore the view :

```
if (apiOperation != null && apiOperation.ignoreJsonView()) {
    jsonViewAnnotation = null;
    jsonViewAnnotationForRequestBody = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this bean to your OpenApiConfiguration

```
@Bean
public ModelConverter modelConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper){
    return new ModelResolver(objectMapper){
        @Override
        protected String decorateModelName(AnnotatedType type, String originalName) {
            return originalName;
        }
    };
}
```